# yield not displaying content in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have moved the code of header from a template in `/views/layouts/header.blade.php`. When I call it using,

```
@yield('layouts.header')
```

or

```
@yield('header')
```

It doesn't display the code.

Comment: @RossWilson can you post that as an answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `[@include][1]` not `@yield`. `@yield` is meant for when you're rendering a `@section` whereas `@include` is meant for simply adding a file.

[@include docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#including-sub-views)

**Base**

```
<body>

@include('layouts.header')

<main>
    @yield('content')
</main>

@include('layouts.footer')

</body>
```

**Child**

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')

    <h1>Hello world</h1>

@stop
```

The only reason you would use `@yield` for the header is if you're having a different header section in all of your child components.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@include('views.layouts.header')` in your page.
`@yield` is used for templates or master pages when you want to extend the section in other pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
**master layout code**

 <html>
 <body>
  @include('layouts.header')

  <main>
      @yield('content')
 </main>

  @include('layouts.footer')

 </body>
```

```
*view blade page code*
@extends('master')

@section('content')
   <h1>Hello world</h1>
@endsection
```